# Optimize image loading iteration in php

Tags: php, laravel, optimization

I have a laravel application in which the user is presented with a list of episodes, each with a screenshot. Each screenshot is loaded inside a foreach loop in the view as per this pseudo code:

```
foreach $episodes as $episode
    $episode->getScreenshot($episodeID);
endforeach
```

The `getScreenshot()` method resolves a specific `ScreenshotLocator` class out of the `IoC` container like so:

```
$screenshotLocator = App::make('\Animekyun\Images\Screenshots\ScreenshotLocator');
```

(I'm reading some things about binding it to the container as a singleton. Is that something to consider? Currently it's not bound at all)

The `ScreenshotLocator` class is designed to build the path to the actual screenshots folder (source below) using the `Episode` model. The screenshots (there are multiple per episode) are all stored in a folder structure and the necessary files are loaded and stored in a `Collection`.

The loading of the screenshots takes `40 ms` out of the `135 ms` for the entire page to load on a Digital Ocean droplet. (10x run benchmark)

So my question is what are some ways to optimize this?

*Source for the `ScreenshotLocator` class:*
http://laravel.io/bin/6L19r

Comment: Did you consider [base64](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/23/when-you-should-use-base64-for-images/) representation, or simple lazy loading with jQuery?

Comment: That's actually a really good idea

Comment: However, that still doesn't really optimize me querying all the images for each episode.